# bootstrap carousel two slide shows appear simultaneously

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have several photo albums (thumbnails, links) on one page. The idea is that when the user clicks on the thumbnail the bootstrap carousel slide show pops up with pictures from this album.

The HTML for one of the albums looks like this (the second one is identical):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Album 1 -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 box">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><span class="spanner"></span></a>

      <div class=thumbnail style="background-image: url(image1.jpg);">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Album 1</h4>
          <p class="photo-text">Album 1 description</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="image1.jpg" alt="image1">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="image2.jpg" alt="image2">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
              </a>

              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
              </a>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I press on the album thumbnail both slide shows pop-up. I assume the problem is with "active" but I am not sure how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure both carousels have a different id. Are you using the id to load the carousel?

Comment: there is only one id I can think of: id="carousel-example-generic". I changed it but nothing has changed. P.S.: I do not have any JS code for slide shows. I am thinking that it is probably a good idea.

Comment: What are you using to make the slideshow appear?

Each slide show (not each slide) needs to use a different id.
Also, see closer to the Album 1 comment, there's an attribute 
data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"
That's in reference with another div that uses that class, try changing that to a different name from the other slideshow as well.